# How to divide a li into 3 equal sections

Tags: html

I want to divide into 3 sections.

```
<li>
<font size="1">
   <div>${comment.postingDate}</div>
   <div><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="like">Like</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:6px;" class="love">Love</a></div> 
   <div><span class="badge"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i><span class="like-count">1</span></span>
        <span class="badge badge-important"><i class="icon-heart"></i><span class="love-count">1</span></span>
   </div>
 </font>
</li>
```

But I think this is wrong design. I am new to html so was wondering how to achieve this efficiently.

The last line of the comment must look like

Date    Like   Love                   Here should be sign with count.

[image]

Comment: can you explain this a bit further? do you have an working example everywhere?

Comment: Just put 3 divs inside, and use css to set the percents.

Comment: so 3 divs in a list? how would that look like?

Comment: I think u cannot put div inside li because the editor showing me error.

Comment: you just have to do this with floats i guess. so you position these divs yourself without a <li>

Comment: I need the Li otherwise i have to change the whole page structure. I mean is it possible to structure without div inside li

Comment: just put another div around it? some kind of wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got what i was looking for.[image]

```
              <li>
                            <font size="1">
                               <span>${comment.postingDate}</span>
                               <span>
                                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="like">Like</a>
                                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:6px;" class="love">Love</a></span> 
                               <span class="pull-right">
                                  <span class="badge"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i><span class="like-count">1</span></span>
                                  <span class="badge badge-important"><i class="icon-heart"></i><span class="love-count">1</span></span>
                               </span>
                             </font>
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation you are looking for the last line in Image.

remove font tag

```
<div class="col">${comment.postingDate}</div>
<div class="col">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="like">Like</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding-left:6px;" class="love">Love</a>
</div> 
<div class="col">
    <span class="badge"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i><span class="like-count">1</span></span>
    <span class="badge badge-important"><i class="icon-heart"></i><span class="love-count">1</span></span>
</div>
```

with style

```
.col{position:relative;float:left;top:0}
```

I think this will do